# How to reduce extremely long delays when sending ajax requests through apache2 reverse proxy?

Tags: apache2, ajax

I'm developing a web application in which the forms send ajax call to the server to save the data.

When running it locally or talking directly to the server the whole request take less than a second but as soon as it has to go through an apache2 reverse proxy the request takes 1.1 minute to complete.

The data is saved quickly on the database but the response is stalled for exactly 1.1 minute every time. In Chrome the delay is listed under "Content Download" even though the response simply consists of a string to make sure the request was successful.

I'm running out of ideas to try and fix this and I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

I have access to the reverse proxy to modify the configuration if needed.

Comment: Could you please post the Proxy configuration? Also, have you tried to perform a network capture (tcpdump, wireshark, etc) to check where exactly is the delay (could be that apache is not delivering to the remote server in time or that the remote server is way too slow or something strange with the browser's request)? If you perform the tcp capture, do it on the apache server for both apache's port and the remote server's port

Comment: Thank you for your comment. While performing the network capture on the apache server with tcpdump I found the cause of the problem and was able to fix it.